# Problem on integration and continuous functions

Tags: integration

> Let $f:[0,1] \to R$ be a continuous function. Then prove
>   $\int_0^1f^2(x)dx \ge (\int_0^1|f(x)|dx)^2$.

I am getting a lot of problems of this type and I don't know how to even begin solving this type of problems.

Can anyone please tell me how to approach problems of this type?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use this case of [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) with your $|f(x)|$ as the $f$ there. Well, since your integrals are on $[0,1]$ define the function as $0$ outside that interval. Take $g(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @RobertZ , I'm sorry I really did not know the answer already exists, I tried to search for it before posting this question. Should I delete this post now?

Comment: @adityabhatt Yes, it is better to remove it.

Comment: @conditionalMethod thank you very much for suggesting  a solution, but as the question and it's solution already exists, I will have to delete the post. Thank you once again though!

Comment: You don't really need to remove anything. You can just let the website do its work. Moreover, there is no solution in the linked post. They chose the wrong duplicate.